# how to clone (minimal proxy pattern) a governance contract from OpenZeppelin

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, proxy-contracts

I am trying to clone oz's governance contract.
However, it looks very complicated.
Many contracts are inherited, and there are some values are set up in their constructors.

In this case, how am I supposed to deal with ?
Please, let me know it..